# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BookingOrderService. Please make sure that the HotelsRepository is available in the BookingModule context

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm starting with nest.js and I am getting this error after I added something into services:

> [Nest] 2348  - 04/11/2023, 23:08:12   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest
> can't resolve dependencies of the BookingOrderService
> (BookingOrdersRepository, BookingOrderDetailRepository, ?). Please
> make sure that the argument HotelsRepository at index [2] is available
> in the BookingModule context.

Potential solutions:

- Is BookingModule a valid NestJS module?
- If HotelsRepository is a provider, is it part of the current BookingModule?
- If HotelsRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within BookingModule?

  ```
  @Module({
  imports: \[ /\* the Module containing HotelsRepository \*/ \]
  })\`
  ```

Here is my codes:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { BookingModule } from './module/module.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'coba1234',
      database: 'realtahotel3',
      entities: ['dist/output/entities/*.js'],
      synchronize: false,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
    BookingModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**module.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { BookingOrderService } from '../booking/booking_order/booking_order.service';
import { BookingOrderDetailService } from '../booking/booking_order_detail/booking_order_detail.service';
import { BookingOrderDetailExtraService } from '../booking/booking_order_detail_extra/booking_order_detail_extra.service';
import { UserBreakfeastService } from '../booking/user_breakfeast/user_breakfeast.service';
import { SpecialOfferCouponsService } from '../booking/special_offer_coupons/special_offer_coupons.service';
import { SpecialOfferService } from '../booking/special_offer/special_offer.service';
import { SpecialOfferController } from '../booking/special_offer/special_offer.controller';
import { SpecialOfferCouponsController } from '../booking/special_offer_coupons/special_offer_coupons.controller';
import { UserBreakfeastController } from '../booking/user_breakfeast/user_breakfeast.controller';
import { BookingOrderDetailExtraController } from '../booking/booking_order_detail_extra/booking_order_detail_extra.controller';
import { BookingOrderDetailController } from '../booking/booking_order_detail/booking_order_detail.controller';
import { BookingOrderController } from '../booking/booking_order/booking_order.controller';
import { BookingOrderDetail } from 'output/entities/BookingOrderDetail';
import { BookingOrderDetailExtra } from 'output/entities/BookingOrderDetailExtra';
import { BookingOrders } from 'output/entities/BookingOrders';
import { UserBreakfeast } from 'output/entities/UserBreakfeast';
import { SpecialOfferCoupons } from 'output/entities/SpecialOfferCoupons';
import { SpecialOffers } from 'output/entities/SpecialOffers';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
        //FOR BOOKING
        BookingOrderDetail,
        BookingOrderDetailExtra,
        BookingOrders,
        UserBreakfeast,
        SpecialOfferCoupons,
        SpecialOffers,
    ]),
    ],
    providers: [BookingOrderService, BookingOrderDetailService, BookingOrderDetailExtraService, UserBreakfeastService, SpecialOfferCouponsService, SpecialOfferService],
    controllers: [SpecialOfferController, SpecialOfferCouponsController, UserBreakfeastController, BookingOrderDetailExtraController, BookingOrderDetailController, BookingOrderController],
    exports: [],
})

export class BookingModule { }
```

**booking_order.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { BookingOrderDetail } from 'output/entities/BookingOrderDetail';
import { BookingOrders } from 'output/entities/BookingOrders';
import { Hotels } from 'output/entities/Hotels';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class BookingOrderService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(BookingOrders) private boorService: Repository<BookingOrders>,
        @InjectRepository(BookingOrderDetail) private bordetService: Repository<BookingOrderDetail>,
        @InjectRepository(Hotels) private hotelService: Repository<Hotels>,
    ) { }

    public async findAll() {
        return await this.boorService.find();
    }

    public async findOne(boorId: number) {
        return await this.boorService.findOne({ where: { boorId } });
    }

    public async CreateBooking(
        boorId: number,
        boorOrderNumber: string,
        boorOrderDate: Date,
        boorArrivalDate: Date,
        boorTotalRoom: number,
        boorTotalGuest: number,
        boorDiscount: string,
        boorTotalTax: string,
        boorTotalAmount: string,
        boorDownPayment: string,
        boorPayType: string,
        boorIsPaid: string,
        boorType: string,
        boorCardnumber: string,
        boorMemberType: string,
        boorStatus: string,
        bookingOrderDetail: BookingOrderDetail,
        boorHotel: Hotels) {
        try {
            await this.boorService.save({
                boorId: boorId,
                boorOrderNumber: boorOrderNumber,
                boorOrderDate: boorOrderDate,
                boorArrivalDate: boorArrivalDate,
                boorTotalRoom: boorTotalRoom,
                boorTotalGuest: boorTotalGuest,
                boorDiscount: boorDiscount,
                boorTotalTax: boorTotalTax,
                boorTotalAmount: boorTotalAmount,
                boorDownPayment: boorDownPayment,
                boorPayType: boorPayType,
                boorIsPaid: boorIsPaid,
                boorType: boorType,
                boorCardnumber: boorCardnumber,
                boorMemberType: boorMemberType,
                boorStatus: boorStatus,
                bookingOrderDetail: bookingOrderDetail,
                boorHotel: boorHotel,
            })
        } catch (error) {
            return error.message;
        }
    }
}
```

**booking_order.controller.ts**

```
import {
    Body,
    Controller,
    Delete,
    Get,
    Param,
    Post,
    Put,
    UploadedFile,
    UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { BookingOrderService } from './booking_order.service';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { BookingOrderDetail } from 'output/entities/BookingOrderDetail';
import { Hotels } from 'output/entities/Hotels';

@Controller('/booking-order')
export class BookingOrderController {
    constructor(private BookingOrderServices: BookingOrderService) { }

    @Get()
    public async getAll() {
        return await this.BookingOrderServices.findAll();
    }

    @Get(':id')
    public async getOne(@Param('id') boorId: number) {
        return await this.BookingOrderServices.findOne(boorId);
    }

    @Post()
    public async Create(@Body('boorId') boorId: number,
        @Body('boorOrderNumber') boorOrderNumber: string,
        @Body('boorOrderDate') boorOrderDate: Date,
        @Body('boorArrivalDate') boorArrivalDate: Date,
        @Body('boorTotalRoom') boorTotalRoom: number,
        @Body('boorTotalGuest') boorTotalGuest: number,
        @Body('boorDiscount') boorDiscount: string,
        @Body('boorTotalTax') boorTotalTax: string,
        @Body('boorTotalAmount') boorTotalAmount: string,
        @Body('boorDownPayment') boorDownPayment: string,
        @Body('boorPayType') boorPayType: string,
        @Body('boorIsPaid') boorIsPaid: string,
        @Body('boorType') boorType: string,
        @Body('boorCardnumber') boorCardnumber: string,
        @Body('boorMemberType') boorMemberType: string,
        @Body('boorStatus') boorStatus: string,
        @Body('bookingOrderDetail') bookingOrderDetail: BookingOrderDetail,
        @Body('boorHotel') boorHotel: Hotels) {
        return await this.BookingOrderServices.CreateBooking(boorId, boorOrderNumber, boorOrderDate, boorArrivalDate, boorTotalRoom, boorTotalGuest, boorDiscount, boorTotalTax, boorTotalAmount, boorDownPayment, boorPayType, boorIsPaid, boorType, boorCardnumber, boorMemberType, boorStatus, bookingOrderDetail, boorHotel);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I need to run the server properly and can be read or get from postman properly without getting any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BookingModule` does not have `Hotels` in the `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` array, nor does it import a module that had `TypeOrmModule` in the `exports` array **and** `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Hotels])` in the `imports` array. Add `Hotels` to the `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` array if you don't have a `HotelsModule`.

As a side note, you should ***really*** clean up  the method signatures. Usually 4 or 5 parameters is considered to be the max in terms of best practices. In your controller you can use `@Body() bookingOrderData` to get the entire body as an object rather than accessing each field, and then you can pass that object directly to the service and the typeorm save call without having to access each field individually.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's really helped me. btw, you mean i can change my parameter at Create to only @Body() bookingOrderData? and how to call the parameter in the properties at the service? i really don't get it. Do you have any related documentation about that? Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, instead of having however many primitive parameters, you can have a single object parameter. Your service method would look like `CreateBooking(bookingOrderData) { await this.bookService.save(bookingOrderData) }`, just keep whittling down those giant methods.